# Virtuoso SPARQL endpoints inference rules

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, endpoint, virtuoso

When using an endpoint that is hosted in *[Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)*, (like [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)), there are a predefined set of rules that can be used (accessible through the  [Inference rules](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?rdfinf) link on the top right).

If I need to use one of these rules I can include as the following within the query space at the endpoint:

```
define input:inference 'ldp'
```

However, when I try to include an external inference rules set, which is not predefined at the previous list, it triggers an error, as the following:

```
define input:inference <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1>
```

> `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: 'define input:inference refers to undefined inference rule set "http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1"`

**QUESTION:**

Is it possible to include external rules from other vocabularies? and if yes, how?

Comment: Is there a reason to suppose that http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1 is a rule set and not just some other ontology?

Comment: I don't think that you can load external rule sets. Shouldn't they first be loaded into Virtuoso by some internal calls and then can be references from e.g. the Web UI? But to be honest, I'm not an expert in Virtuoso, so my answer has a high chance to be wrong.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yes there is. I believe that it is (indeed) ontology, you are right. However, if you check the inference rules provided by the endpoint which are linked in the question (Inference rules link), you can find that this is a bit misleading notation by Virtuoso. What they really are is a kind of vocabulary inclusion. At least this is what I think.

Comment: Yes, there is a list of inference rule sets that the DBpedia endpoint supports, but I don't think that those are *defined* in the ontologies that they might happen to be named after.  I don't think that those are being read from those URIs;  I think those URIs are just being used to identify the ruleset.  I'm not a Virtuoso expert, though, so I can't be certain of that.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I agree with that!

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions often get faster and more accurate responses when asked in Virtuoso-specific spaces, such as the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the public [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a confidential [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). [Feature-specific docs](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule.html) can also help.

Comment: @MedianHilal "What they really are is a kind of vocabulary inclusion. At least this is what I think." Why guess like this? Why not ask directly? No, an ontology -- a vocabulary -- is not automatically the same as an inference rule set, though they may appear to be so at a glance.

Comment: @TallTed, I know that an ontology is different from an inference rule. However, if you check what they provide as 'inference rules' at Dbpedia sparql endpoint by Vituoso, like for example 'http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl', this is clearly an ontology, isn't it? I cannot understand the why calling it 'inference rule'.

Comment: @MedianHilal, have you read the [Virtuoso docs](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule.html) I linked before, which go into much detail? Or the [associated tutorials](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSPARQLReasoningTutorial)? One example —  many people still mis-understand and mis-use `owl:samAs` — so you *might* want to enable inference over `subClass/subProperty` and others but *not* include `owl:sameAs` — which you can do with inference rules, but not with the OWL ontology, per se.

Answer (score 0):

The DBpedia instance (and any other Virtuoso instance, for that matter) includes a list of preloaded inference rules. Naturally, for a variety of reasons (security, fair use, etc.), we don't allow ad-hoc inclusion of inference rules from external sources.

Note: An inference rule in Virtuoso is a mapping between a Rule and an Ontology (see [Using British Royal Family Data Snippets — to demonstrate SPARQL Query Language-based Reasoning & Inference](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/using-british-royal-family-data-snippets-to-demonstrate-sparql-query-language-based-reasoning-56626a152419#.oe8a2ghjs)). It's the Rule Name that's used in the Inference Rule pragma of the query, which then indicates the following to the SPARQL processor:

1. Need to invoke inference context
2. Specific Rules (again, mappings to an Ontology where relation semantics are defined) to be invoked.