# Is it possible to infer new knowledge about an ontology only from a query in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, geosparql

Is it possible to infer new knowledge about an ontology only from a query in SPARQL?

I have a question about the use of the SPARQL language about ontologies. So far I have thought that SPARQL is the equivalent to the SQL language in the relational databases, that is to say, that with SPARQL it is only possible to consult the data that are explicitly in the ontology, without having access to the data that can be inferred , leaving the responsibility of the inference to the reasoners.

However, I have read documents from which I infer that SPARQL does have the capacity to infer implicit and non-explicit knowledge in the ontology. Is my inference true? That is, is it possible to infer knowledge through a SPARQL query without the need for a reasoner? If the answer is true, then what advantages does the use of a reasoner have over the use of SPARQL?

Greetings, Manuel Puebla.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-entailment/) please. And then don't forget, "reasoning" is a very generic term. There are indeed different types of reasoning, and even in deductive reasoning there are different approaches that are differently powerful. Moreover, read about forward and backward chaining - just my two cents

Comment: I appreciate your response, but it does not answer my question, it only suggests a bibliography.

Until now, to infer new knowledge I have used the tools called reasoners (Pellet, Racer, HermiT, among others) joined to framework like OWLAPI or JENA. I have never used SPARQL for this and I thought it was not possible to do so, that with SPARQL I could only consult the data that was explicitly. What I need to know is if I can do the same with SPARQL without the aforementioned tools.

Greetings.

Comment: Duplicate. See users@jena mailing list: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/e81465ecc1bca25bb32c5c4c0aa250a9b18a1a7682cfed5104bed4b4@%3Cusers.jena.apache.org%3E

Comment: What does geosparql have to do with this question?

Comment: @Manuel And I referred to SPARQL 1.1 entailment regimes in my link. What do think is this about? Yes, it's inference in SPARQL. So my comment does answer your question. To keep it short, behind the scenes, it's still some reasoning mechanism, either it's done in a) advance and materializes all inferences such that you query the materialized graph or b) on the fly by means of backward-chaining aka query rewriting.

Comment: And indeed, there is a difference between using a standard OWL reasoner and SPARQL entailment. Think about completeness

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on-the-fly inference may be a feature of the SPARQL processor, so you can get the benefits of inference/reasoning directly from a SPARQL query.  (See [Virtuoso SPARQL endpoints inference rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430656/virtuoso-sparql-endpoints-inference-rules) for some discussion of how this is done in Virtuoso, for example.)